# How do I set my default editor to emacs -nw in my .Rprofile?

Tags: r, emacs, rprofile

As the question says, I want my default editor in R (e.g. when I do fix(fn_name)) to be the non-windowed mode of emacs as opposed to the windowed mode. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file somewhere (I use a `bin` directory under my home), called `emacsnw` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs -nw "$@"
```

and make it executable: `chmod 755 emacsnw`

Then you can do `options(editor="/home/me/bin/emacsnw")` and that will then call it.

Note I can never remember if `"$@"` or `"$*"` is the right way to pass args through a script, but this seems to work for `fix()`.

Comment: Awesome, this works exactly as you listed it! THanks!

Comment: I think `"$@"` is generally the right thing.  It expands each parameter individually and wraps them each in quotes.  So it would be like `emacsnw "file name with spaces" "more spaces"` -> `emacs -nw "file name with spaces" "more spaces"` rather than `emacs -nw file name with spaces more spaces` or `emacs -nw "file name with spaces more spaces"`.